# How to impersonate a federated user given an email address

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom policy that allows a handful of users the ability to authenticate as themselves but then enter an email address of another user they need to impersonate (for help desk calls, etc). The users in the AAD B2C directory are of two types -- 1) local users (third party partners) and 2) federated users from our internal, corporate AAD. Impersonating the local users is working. The solution is based off of sample github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/

What is not working is impersonating federated users. What I'd like to do is read the user based on otherMails (which will be unique among active users)but when I attempt to upload a custom policy with a step to Read the user from the B2C directory by the otherMails claim I get a validation message '.Input Claim 'otherMails' is not supported in Azure Active Directory Provider technical profile 'SelfAsserted-TargetEmailExchangeFederated' of policy 'B2C_1A_Impersonation'.

'otherMails' is defined in the base policy so it seems it is just not supported to 'Read' on. I get this same error message if I try the mailNickname attribute. I can successfully upload and run the policy searching by other attributes such as employeeId, or immutableId however these have other limitations (size, uniqueness) that don't make them viable to store email addresses in.

Is there a way to read a user profile by otherMails?

If not, is there another field I could use? (I tried adding an extended attribute, policy would run but the account would not be found).

Short of either of those, is there a way to read the account from our corporate AAD by email from the custom policy? (calling the graph api, etc?)

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, what I ended up doing was creating a custom api that wrapped the graph api to look up identities based on entered email and then called out to the api from the impersonation policy.

similar to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw

for reference:
[Find a User by Email Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327823/find-a-user-by-email-address)